# Cannot install Fastquant using pip on OSX

Tags: python, python-3.x, macos, numpy, pip

Problem description
Can't install Fastquant

Environment

```
platform (e.g. Linux, OSX, Windows): OSX
fastquant version (e.g. 0.1.3.17): latest version
installation method (e.g. pip, conda, source): pip
```

I'm getting this error message: https://gist.github.com/datomnurdin/9316fc269c71b4a6ca3f5a947a1c0272

Comment: Did you tried this command : python -m pip install fastquant

Comment: You are talking about MacOS, but your log contains windows paths: `command: 'c:\users\nurdin\appdata\local\programs\python\python39\python.exe'`. Please review your question, adding a [mcve] that contains the `pip install` command you have used and the full output log.

Answer (score 0):

Can you try updating your fastquant package? We've just fixed an issue with the new python 3.9

`pip install fastquant --upgrade`